# Fields missing from 'Available Fields' list when Editing/creating list view

Tags: fields, list-view

I am Admin and want to update a "list view" in opportunity Object
I want to add the standard lookup field "Price Book" to the list,
but **it is not available in the "Available fields"**
Why is it missing for god sake??
I have permission to the field and see it in the page layout.
same issue with "Primary Campaign Source" and many many other fields

Comment: Are you trying to add these as columns, or in the filter for the list view?

Comment: Trying to add as Column, but @Vinay already answer that this is as SF designed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard fields like primary campaign source, price book etc., fields are not available on Opportunity List Views and this is working as designed.

Workaround is to create a formula field called something like Primary Campaign Formula and have it display the text field of the name of the campaign and similar with other fields as well.

Check more details on [Add 'Primary Campaign Source' field on Opportunity List View](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383953&type=1).